# re.sub: non-greedy doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code in ipython. I expect it to remove the beginning "ab" since .*? is a non-greedy one. But why it remove all the way up to the last b?

```
  In [15]: b="abcabcabc"

  In [16]: re.sub(".*?b","",b)
  Out[16]: 'c'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because, by default, `re.sub()` will search and replace all occurrences

```
>>> import re
>>> b="abcabcabc"
>>> re.sub(".*?b","",b)
'c'
>>> re.sub("^.*?b","",b)
'cabcabc'
>>> re.sub(".*?b","",b, count=1)
'cabcabc'
>>> re.sub(".*?b","",b, count=2)
'cabc'
```

From [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The *python* [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) says:

> The optional argument count is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced; count must be a non-negative integer. If omitted or zero, **all occurrences will be replaced**

So, you can call `re.sub` with `count=1` to get your desired result:

```
re.sub(".*?b", "", b, 1)
#output
'cabcabc'
```